# Netbeans - storing username in the session bean?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, parameters, session-bean

I am currently trying to pass the username to a servlet in netbeans. The username is input in the login, such that

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

I then access this username in servletA by

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

After that a user is taken to a welcome page which has a button which activates servletB, that I want to pass the username parameter to. When I try accessing it by **username** is doesn't work because that value is only on the login page.

I read that in theory it can be done by storing the username in the SessionBean, but I am not sure how to do that. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    session.setAttribute("userName", username);
```

You can find a full example [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/http-session-in-session-tracking).

Comment: Hi Sundararaj, 
Thank you for your help, that's what I have done in servletA
            `HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            session.setAttribute("username", username);`

but because username doesn't in the webpage that requests servletB i get an error when trying to do the same.